# Do I need to check out and check in my baggage in Toronto, which is where my layover is

Tags: customs-and-immigration, luggage, international-travel

I will be flying from Iceland to Los Angeles. The first part of my trip is from Reykjavik to Toronto, with Icelandair, and the second part of my trip is from Toronto to Los Angeles, with Air Canada. I wonder if I need to take my baggage, go through customs, and check in my baggage in Toronto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to do a whole nine yards, Canada Border Services, Claim Baggage, Check-in, Baggage Drop-Off, Security, U.S. Customs & Border Protection (since it's a pre-clearance airport). It'll be a lot of fun (not).

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you know whether the bags have to clear both Canadian and US customs in Toronto?

Comment: Yes. You enter into Canada first and then preclear -- your flight will land as a domestic one.